# Metronome: loud sound indicates first or last note?

Tags: metronomes

Usually, does the loud sound of a metronome indicate the first note to play or the last one ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, a the loud click/bell is used to indicate the first beat of the bar. In 4/4 it would go '**loud**, soft, soft, soft' and keep repeating. In 3/4 it would go, '**loud**, soft, soft'. But not all music starts on the first beat of the bar. For example, *Happy Birthday To You* starts with an anacrusis or pick up notes on the third beat of the 3/4 bar, so you would wait for '**loud**, soft' and start on the next click (which will be 'soft') with 'ha-ppy'. 'Birth-' will be on the loud click/bell that starts the next bar.

Comment: Right answer to a slightly strangely worded question. +1. I've gone a tad further in another answer.

Answer (score 3):

As Areel says, the loud click is usually deemed to indicate the first beat of each bar. But your question asks about the *first note to play*. That is often not the same place as the first beat of a bar - and the same applies to the last note you play. (Which actually is more likely to be on beat 1).

Going a bit further, that loud click doesn't necessarily *have* to be the first beat. It's quite fun to imagine any click to actually be the *offbeat*, or the & between the beats. So you could use the loud click to be anything you want - although most people, especially beginners, will regard it as **beat 1**.

Answer (score 1):

You are perfectly free to choose, whatever seems appropriate, since the metronome is completely neutral in this respect.

Two items to consider:

- Most electronic metronomes have a setting, where they don't distinguish between special/other beats. The distinction is most important anyway, when starting with a new piece, to ensure one stays in the tempo. So one may be drop it later.
- When dealing with syncopations it is sometimes suggested, to have the sounds *in the middle* of the beats to indicate the transition to the next note instead.